# SQL summarize row into column (pivot?)

Tags: sql, row, pivot

I have a list of persons with the respective earnings by company like this

```
Company_code Person Date    Earning1 Earning2
1            Jonh   2014-01 100      200
2            Jonh   2014-01 300      400
1            Jonh   2014-02 500      600
1            Peter  2014-01 300      400
1            Peter  2014-02 500      600
```

And I would like to summarize into this:

```
Company_code Person 2014-01_E1 2014-01_E2 2014-02_E1 2014-02_E2
1            Jonh   100        200        300        400
2            Jonh   500        600
1            Peter  300        400        500        600
```

For what I've searched maybe this can be done with the Pivot function but since I'm not looking for an aggregation (min, max, etc) I'm not understanding how I can do it.
The number of dates in my case is short (about 10 values) so we can call it a given and fixed value.

Comment: Do you expect the number of columns to be dynamic depending on the data in the table or do you assume only a couple of months?

Comment: No, it can be constant (updated the question). Thanks for your interest

Comment: what about doing on the app languaje?

Comment: Is your example output accurate? Not sure what logic you'd be after to get that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
with t(Company_code, Person, Dt, Earning1, Earning2) as (
  select 1, 'Jonh', to_date('2014-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 100, 200 from dual union all
  select 2, 'Jonh', to_date('2014-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 300, 400 from dual union all
  select 1, 'Jonh', to_date('2014-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 500, 600 from dual union all
  select 1, 'Peter', to_date('2014-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 300, 400 from dual union all
  select 1, 'Peter', to_date('2014-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 500, 600 from dual
)
select * 
  from t
 pivot ( 
     sum(Earning1) e1
   , sum(Earning2) e2 
 for dt in (
     to_date('2014-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') "2014-01"
   , to_date('2014-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') "2014-02"
 )
)

COMPANY_CODE    PERSON  2014-01_E1  2014-01_E2  2014-02_E1  2014-02_E2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
           2    Jonh           300         400           -           -
           1    Peter          300         400         500         600
           1    Jonh           100         200         500         600
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer it works correctly. Actually I've tried that before but I had other colums which had different values between cells so they didnt aggregate ... your example made me stick to basics and undestand the real problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @zaratustra-> what if I have some columns I want to ignore in the Pivot process? In this case, imagine I have a set of description columns which I want to ignore - by copying any of the values to the pivot table

Comment: Start a new question, please, I don't understand what you want, it is really difficult to describe everything in the comment.